# Получить ip wan

Tags: сеть

Всем привет не могу узнать какой же на самом деле у меня WAN IP. Лазя по настройкам роутера я обнаружил, что на WAN IP не совпадает с общедоступным IP(то есть IP который показывает 2ip.ru), и я сделал вывод, что мой провайдер использует у себя т.н GS-NAT, значит WAN IP(внешний IP моего роутера) на самом то деле является адресом грубо говоря в локальной сети провайдера(там где DHCP генерирует WAN IPшники всем своим абонементам), то есть он не имеет никакого отношения к общедоступному IP(кстати на счет этого общедоступного IP - если например он равен 31.132.158.101, то это значит он общий для всех юзеров провайдеров, то есть если я например играю в онлайн игру в которой мой акк зареган на общедоступный IP 31.132.158.101. Значит если в моем городе, кто то играет в эту же онлайн игру, то у этого человека имеется акк с зареганым IP 31.132.158.101 и если фактически его забанят и в игре будет стоять блокировка по IP, значит и меня тоже забанят???). В настройках роутера я так и не понял какой адрес является WAN IP:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть если я не ошибся пунктом в настройках, значит WAN IP в теории = 100.83.22.4. Я поверил, и пошел чекать трасировку маршрута от моего хоста до vk.com:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему здесь нету упоминания WAN IP = 100.83.22.4? Почему вмнесто него 100.83.0.1 и даже при перезагрузки роутера это значение не изменилось. И собстна какой здесь на самом деле у меня WAN IP?

Comment: 100.83.0.1 — это ближайший провайдерский роутер, IP которого не должен совпадать с вашим WAN IP. А вот у вашего роутера есть целых два IP-адреса — 192.168.100.1 и собственно WAN IP 100.83.22.4

Comment: А «почему здесь нету упоминания» — потому что ваш компьютер находится в сети 192.168 и связывается с роутером именно через IP-адрес 192.168.100.1

Comment: Получается 192.168.100.1 это адрес роутера для моей локальной сети, а 100.83.22.4 - это ip роутера в сети провайдера?

Comment: Про общедоступный IP не знаете ответа, верно?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если просто, то есть понятия "серого" и "белого" IP адресов (внешних - WAN IP).
По умолчанию провайдеры выделяют пользователям "серый" IP адрес - это динамический адрес, выделенный вам на время сессии (т.е. он у вас будет меняться при  каждом новом входе в сеть, предположу, что может и чаще - не очень важно в контексте вопроса). Если вам нужен постоянный несменяемый WAN IP (например, если внешний сервер у себя решили сделать или куда-то на ftp ходить, где пропуск по конкретному IP, я такой ftp организовывал сам себе когда-то), то за определённую ежемесячную плату вам провайдер его даст ("белый" IP адрес, он же статический IP адрес).

Исходя из вышенаписанного:
"если фактически его забанят и в игре будет стоять блокировка по IP, значит и меня тоже забанят???" - нет, вряд ли забанят, у вас другой динамический IP, как минимум, внутри сети провайдера. Банят обычно не по IP поэтому, как понимаю, так как можно слишком много кого забанить. Да и не эффективно это - обойдут по VPN, например. Скорее, по паролю или даже по "железу" забанят.
Исследование своего динамического IP несёт разве что познавательную ценность. Но хорошо, что вы об этом задумались - +1 за вопрос и самостоятельные исследования:-)

Остальные ответы даны уже @andreymal в комментариях.

Comment: -> нет, не забанят, у вас другой динамический IP     Стоп.... динамический ip(WAN IP или внешний IP в нашем примере пускай будет = 100.83.22.4) это грубо говоря я понимаю, как адрес, который находится только в сети провайдера, то есть он не имеет доступа в сеть(а фактически этот диапазон адресов содержит своих на данный момент подключенных абонементов).

Comment: А сам WAN IP маршрутизирован в глобальную сеть(в нашем примере 31.132.158.101). Следовательно если мы подключаемся к vk.com, то он не может в качестве ответа прислать ответ на адрес 100.83.22.4, который вы назвали ДИНМАЧЕСКИМ, потому что диапазон 100.xxx.xxx.xxx юзает не только один провайдер и может в мире быть сотни, да даже 100.83.22.4 он тупо никак не доступен в глобальную сеть(это тоже самое как шлюз внутреннего роутера 192.168.100.1, он же не один в мире а его фактически используют "все компы" ).

Comment: Это я рассказал как я понимаю серый IP, то есть еще раз: в сером IP динамический адрес он только с точки зрения сети ПРОВАЙДЕРА(ну даже как наши компы в локальной сети 192.168.0.1, 192.168.0.2, 192.168.0.3, а в случае провайдера это просто внешние ip роутеров клиента), а с точки зрения vk.com он нихера не динмаческий(доказательство тому 2ip.ru он всегда показывает один и тот же адрес в глобальной сети). А статический адрес должен быть таким: WAN IP = глобальный адрес сети, то есть внешний адрес роутера уже не указывает в локальную сеть провайдера, а уже показывает в ГЛОБАЛЬНУЮ СЕТЬ.

Comment: Вот как я это понимаю,но не уверен так ли это...

Comment: @Materender «2ip.ru он всегда показывает один и тот же адрес в глобальной сети» — даже после перезагрузки роутера?

Comment: До этого я вроде бы проверял, но насколько помню он совпал после перезагрузки, в этом раз не. Значит глобальный адрес не один для всех клиентов. Значит в случае с динамическими адресами меняются и WAN IP и ip глобальной сети. А в случае статической не меняется глобальный ip.

Comment: Получается при договоре с провайдером о белом IP, то он выделит ГЛОБАЛЬНЫЙ IP, который в 2ip.ru не меняется. Значит по сути внешний IP адрес роутера(WAN) при белом IP будет = ГЛОБАЛЬНЫЙ IP, который показывает  2ip.ru?

Comment: Вы правильно подметили, я был не очень конкретен.  Я имел в виду, что вряд ли начнут банить целые подсети, не слышал о таком, хотя какой-то риск есть, верно. Да, серый IP является внутренним в сети. Видит вас ваш провайдер, как правило, но может быть и ситуация, что ваш временный адрес станет виден (скорее, у каких-то старых провайдеров. Я знаю, что такой риск есть, но без деталей, так что осторожнее с "всегда показывает один и тот же адрес в глобальной сети" - это не догма).

Comment: Да, вы правы, при договоре с провайдером должно быть так: "внешний IP адрес роутера(WAN) при белом IP будет = ГЛОБАЛЬНЫЙ IP, который показывает 2ip.ru" Я сам это раньше наблюдал для себя.

Comment: Подправил свой ответ и расширил (порылся по сети ещё - прав я был с догадкой своей, давно уже по IP не банят). Можете принимать ответ, если больше нет вопросов:-)

Comment: А вот при сером IP, глобальный IP же разделяется с абонементами, то есть у нескольких абонементах может быть одинаковый IP в глобальной сети. Да? А белый IP при заключении договора, как бы никому кроме владельца не выдается. Я сделал такой вывод, потому что подумал зачем еще было провайдерам придумывать серый IP)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137077/discussion-between--and-materender).